# Akka http 401 on not authenticated endpoint

Tags: scala, http, akka

I have the following routes definition

```scala
private val routes: Route =
    concat(
      pathEnd {
        get {
          handleErrorsAndReport("list_foos") {
            
          }
        }
      },
      path(Segment) { fooId =>
        get {
          handleErrorsAndReport("get_foo") {
            rejectEmptyResponse(
              complete(service.do(fooId))
            )
          }
        }
      },
      pathEnd {
        authenticateBasic(
          realm = "Secure scope",
          scopesAuthenticator
        ) { scopes =>
          post {
            handleErrorsAndReport("create_foo") {
             
            }
          }
        }
      },
      path(Segment) { fooId =>
        authenticateBasic(
          realm = "Secure scopes",
          scopesAuthenticator
        ) { scopes =>
          concat(
            put {
              handleErrorsAndReport("update_foo") {
              
              }
            },
            delete {
              handleErrorsAndReport("delete_foo") {
               
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
    )
```

I am trying to consume the `get_foo`  endpoint. I have created a unit test for that and it looks like this

```scala
"allow get operation on foo without authentication present" in {
      Get("/foos/{some_id}") ~> routes ~> check {
        status shouldBe StatusCodes.NotFound
      }
    }
```

While debugging the test I can see that the route is correctly identified and I can access the code inside the route. The service code inside the `get_foo` route produces a None and `complete(None)` creates a rejection since it's an empty response and I have the `rejectEmptyResponse` directive. So I would expect that I would get a 404 response based on the `handleErrorsAndReport` directive that I have defined. The error handler looks like this

```scala
  private def handleErrorsAndReport(endpoint: String): Directive0 = extractRequestContext.flatMap { ctx =>
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    mapResponse { resp =>
      // store response related metrics and return response
      resp
    } & handleExceptions(exceptionHandler)
  }

  private val exceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler = {

    def handle(e: Throwable, responseCode: StatusCode, errorMessage: Option[String]): Route = {
      extractRequest { request =>        

        val response = (responseCode, errorMessage) match {
          case (InternalServerError, _) => "Internal Server Error"
          case (_, Some(message)) => message
          case _ => "Bad Request"
        }

        complete(HttpResponse(responseCode, entity = response))
      }
    }

    ExceptionHandler {
      case e@AError(description) => handle(e, BadRequest, Some(description))
      case e: BError => handle(e, InternalServerError, Some(e.errorMessage))
      case e: CError => handle(e, BadRequest, Some(e.errorMessage))
      case e: DError => handle(e, BadRequest, Some(e.errorMessage))
      case e: EError => handle(e, BadRequest, Some(e.errorMessage))
      case e@FException(filter) => handle(e, BadRequest, Some(s"bla"))
      case other => handle(other, InternalServerError, Option(other.getMessage))
    }
  }
```

What I am getting though is a 401 Unauthorized. How can this be?
As I was debugging the code I noticed that the control flow never enters my exception handler - I added breakpoints everywhere inside...

Comment: where have you implemented the `handleErrorsAndReport` route? please add that to the question.

Comment: @James I updated the question with the exceptions handler. fyi debugging the code, the control flow never enters my exception handler - I added breakpoints everywhere inside.

Comment: What is the `PathMatcher` you use in `Segment`? why is `Segment` capitalized. `path` accepts a `PathMatcher` as argument. So either it should be directly mentioned or defined inside a var or val passed into it.

Comment: Currently, it is obvious that the execution gets into one of the paths with `authenticateBasic`. Based on the value the `Segment` holds, you might be able to see how. Also, `path(Segment)` and `pathEnd` are repeated twice in the same `concat`. What is the point of that? please see [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/routes.html#composing-routes). If a higher route rejects, it tries it with the next one. So that explains it, why the execution of your code ends up in the `authenticateBasic` route and gets rejected with 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: I put the paths like this since based on `concat` definition "Tries the supplied routes in sequence, returning the result of the first route that doesn't reject the request". So I thought that I'd start with the non authenticated paths first

Comment: Moreover, it is obvious that `authenticateBasic` is failing the authentication with the current implementation of it and the request you send to it.

Comment: Ok, so if a non-authenticated path rejects, you don’t necessarily get a 404. it is going to be matched against an authenticated route, and if it matches and fails to authenticate, then you get 401.

Comment: You can simply put the authenticated routes under an `/auth/` url section, so that this clash would not happen.

Comment: So what happened to “While debugging the test I can see that the route is correctly identified and I can access the code inside the route.” if it does not enter your exception handler? Maybe edit the question.

Comment: I'm not really at liberty to change the API here and change the request path. " so if a non-authenticated path rejects, you don’t necessarily get a 404. it is going to be matched against an authenticated route" but how will it match an authenticated route when the routes only match with the a non-authenticated route?

Comment: It really does not enter the exception handler. I guess there's a interleaving rejection handler somewhere is there that skips my exception handler. Thanks for your responses btw. I've been stack here for a lot of time.

Comment: This happens due to having identical url. The matching happens based on the url, not based on either the authentication headers or the request body. So it first matches with the unauthenticated route, then after rejection, it matches the authenticated route with identical url.

Comment: So the HTTP verb does not matter... (?)

Comment: It does matter but you have not separated routes based on that, for example, post or get.

Comment: I mean regardless of whether your request is get or post, the code processes the request the same way. Because you have not separated that.

Comment: See [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/method-directives/index.html) for samples.

Comment: These examples use the `~>` syntax. Changing into this would require a major refactoring to the code but maybe I can revert the order of directives from `path{verb{}}` to `verb{path{}}`

Comment: aha, I got it. the separation happens in the lower level directive, so for your code to reject the get request in the `authenticateBasic` route, you have to put the `authenticateBasic` route inside the `post`, `put`, or `delete` directive, not vice versa. Your code, first matches the `authenticateBasic` route, then after authentication, only if it is successful, checks the HTTP method.

Comment: aha... I can try that

Comment: No, don’t refactor, just wrap `pathEnd {
        authenticateBasic(` inside `post` instead of putting the `post` inside of it in the third directive. Then create a fourth directive inside `concat` wrapping ` path(Segment) { fooId =>
        authenticateBasic(` with `put` and a fifth one wrapping it with `delete`.

Comment: I added the sample in the answer.

Comment: Hey, I would appreciate an upvote for the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that, after the rejection of request in the unauthenticated directive, the match happens against an authenticated route with the same url. So the authentication fails and results in 401 unauthorized instead of 404.

For solving it, you need to prevent this match against the authenticated route, after the failure of the unauthenticated route with the `GET` method, by wrapping it inside `post`, `put`, and `delete` routes so that the `GET` requests cannot reach it.

So it can be written as

```
private val routes: Route =
    concat(
      pathEnd {
        get {
          handleErrorsAndReport("list_foos") {
            
          }
        }
      },
      path(Segment) { fooId =>
        get {
          handleErrorsAndReport("get_foo") {
            rejectEmptyResponse(
              complete(service.do(fooId))
            )
          }
        }
      },
      post {
         pathEnd {
          authenticateBasic(
            realm = "Secure scope",
            scopesAuthenticator
          ) { scopes =>
          
               handleErrorsAndReport("create_foo") {
               }
             
            }
         }
      },
      put{
         path(Segment) { fooId =>
           authenticateBasic(
           realm = "Secure scopes",
           scopesAuthenticator
          ) { scopes =>
          
              handleErrorsAndReport("update_foo") {

              }
            }
        }
      },
      delete{
         path(Segment) { fooId =>
           authenticateBasic(
           realm = "Secure scopes",
           scopesAuthenticator
          ) { scopes =>
          
              handleErrorsAndReport(“delete_foo") {

              }
           }
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: Not I get a different error message for create_foo and get_foo. For create_foo I get a `AuthenticationFailedRejection` but the status is not set to 401. Actually when I try to retrieve the status (`status shouldBe StatusCodes.Unauthorized`) my test fails. But the test succeeds when I just assert that `rejection shouldBe AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing,HttpChallenge("Basic","Secure scope",Map("charset" -> "UTF-8")))`

Comment: and for get_foo the request gets rejected but I cannot access the rejection list somehow

Comment: @Niko, the create_foo case is expected according to the official [docs](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/AuthenticationFailedRejection.html) you can access the cause by calling the `.cause` method on it.

Comment: @Niko, and in the case of get_foo, the behavior is also expected according to [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/rejectEmptyResponse.html). So when there is something to be returned by `service.do(fooId)` it returns that; when there is nothing to be retuned, the `rejectEmptyResponse` “replaces a response with no content with an empty rejection."

Comment: @Niko your `service.do(fooId)` has to return an `Option`. Whenever it has a response, it has to return `Some`; otherwise `None`, so that the `rejectEmptyResponse` would reject with just 401 and no content.

Comment: Based on [these docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authenticateBasic.html)  `AuthenticationFailedRejection` is mapped to a 410 status by default but in my case I cannot  even access the status code.

Comment: and in the case of get_foo  I would expect the default behavior of `rejectEmptyResponse` which based on [these docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/rejectEmptyResponse.html) is 404 but still in my case there is no status available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236853/discussion-between-niko-and-james).